# WebStorm - Command Line Launcher is missing from the Tools panel on Windows 10

Tags: command-line, webstorm

I'm trying to follow this guide http://www.wisdomofjim.com/blog/webstorm-secret-tip-creating-command-line-launcher to add support for opening WebStorm in the current directory from a command line, but there is no such option in the Tools section:

[image: No such option]

Can someone explain why this option is not available?

Answer (score 2):

**Command Line launcher** is only available on UNIX platforms, there is no such option for Windows. If you miss it, please vote for [IDEA-114307](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114307). If you like to start WebStorm from command prompt, open cmd console, `cd` to `%WS_install_dir%/bin` and run either `webstorm64.exe` or `webstorm.bat`. If you like to start it from any directory, add `%WS_install_dir%/bin` to your system `%PATH%`

See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/opening-files-from-command-line.html

Comment: Can I somehow make a shorter name for webstorm64.exe ? I would like to type smth like "ws ."

Comment: you can create your own batch script with preferred name that would call the webstorm64.exe and add this script to your %PATH% - you will then be able to call it from anywhere using the specified name